# Adding parameter to Json converter during deserialization with converter defined for property

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, jsonconverter

I would like to pass a parameter to the Json converter at the time of deserialization. At the same time, I would like the converter to execute only for the properties indicated by the attribute.

```
    public class Contract
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(MyJsonConverter))]
        public string Property { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    string parameter = "value";
    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Converters = { new MyJsonConverter(parameter) },
    };

    var contract = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contract>(json, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

```
    public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        private readonly string _parameter;

        public MyJsonConverter(string parameter)
        {
            _parameter = parameter;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            //
        }

        public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // use _parameter here
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

I know that the JsonConverter attribute accepts parameters for the converter, but then I would have to add one parameter to the Contract class permanently.

`[JsonConverter(typeof(MyJsonConverter), <parameters>)]`

I would like the parameters to be dynamically provided at the time of deserialization - how do I achieve this?

Comment: I was always wondering what the people need a custom converter for. You could post your json too and explaing why do you need a custom converter and the parameters. It could help to understand what are you doing

Comment: Sounds like you have a _god_ class that holds arbitrary data that should be serialized to JSON and depending on the data you want to create different JSON result strings. In these cases I'd normally break up the _god_ class into seperate classes (sharing a base class or interface) which can all be individually configured on how to be serialized. Additionally a converter will be made, that gets a _god_ instance and returns a _concrete_ instance as the base type or interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`StreamingContext.Context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext.context) from [`JsonSerializerSettings.Context`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Context.htm) to pass data into a JsonConverter.

First, define the following interface and classes to cache data, keyed by `System.Type`, inside a `StreamingContext`:

```
public static class StreamingContextExtensions
{
    public static StreamingContext AddTypeData(this StreamingContext context, Type type, object? data)
    {
        var c = context.Context;
        IStreamingContextTypeDataDictionary dictionary;
        if (context.Context == null)
            dictionary = new StreamingContextTypeDataDictionary();
        else if (context.Context is IStreamingContextTypeDataDictionary d)
            dictionary = d;
        else 
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("context.Context is already populated with {0}", context.Context));
        dictionary.AddData(type, data);
        return new StreamingContext(context.State, dictionary);
    }
    
    public static bool TryGetTypeData(this StreamingContext context, Type type, out object? data)
    {
        IStreamingContextTypeDataDictionary? dictionary = context.Context as IStreamingContextTypeDataDictionary;
        if (dictionary == null)
        {
            data = null;
            return false;
        }
        return dictionary.TryGetData(type, out data);
    }
}

public interface IStreamingContextTypeDataDictionary
{
    public void AddData(Type type, object? data);
    public bool TryGetData(Type type, out object? data);
}

class StreamingContextTypeDataDictionary : IStreamingContextTypeDataDictionary
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, object?> dictionary = new ();
    public void AddData(Type type, object? data) => dictionary.Add(type, data);
    public bool TryGetData(Type type, out object? data) => dictionary.TryGetValue(type, out data);
}
```

Then rewrite `MyConverter` as follows:

```
public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(string);

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Grab parameter from serializer.Context.  Use some default value (here "") if not present.
        var _parameter = serializer.Context.TryGetTypeData(typeof(MyJsonConverter), out var s) ? (string?)s : "";
        // Use _parameter as required, e.g.
        return _parameter + (string?)JToken.Load(reader);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer) => 
        writer.WriteValue((string)value!);
}
```

And you will be able to deserialize as follows:

```
var _parameter = "my runtime parameter: ";
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All)
        .AddTypeData(typeof(MyJsonConverter), _parameter),
    // Add any other required customizations,
};

var contract = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contract>(json, settings);
```

Notes:

- The data cached inside the `StreamingContext` is keyed by type so that multiple converters could access cached data inside without interfering with each other.  The type used should be the converter type, not the property type.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yyMnxp).

Honestly though I don't recommend this design.  `StreamingContext` is unfamiliar to current .NET programmers (it's a holdover from binary serialization) and it feels completely surprising to use it to pass data deep down into some `JsonConverter.ReadJson()` method.

**As an alternative**, you might consider creating a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that replaces the default `MyJsonConverter` applied at compile time with a different instance that has the required parameters.

First, define the following contract resolver:

```
public class ConverterReplacingContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly Dictionary<(Type type, string name), JsonConverter?> replacements;
    
    public ConverterReplacingContractResolver(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<(Type type, string name), JsonConverter?>> replacements) =>
        this.replacements = (replacements ?? throw new ArgumentNullException()).ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (member.DeclaringType != null && replacements.TryGetValue((member.DeclaringType, member.Name), out var converter))
            property.Converter = converter;
        return property;
    }
}
```

Then modify `MyJsonConverter` so it has a default constructor with a default value for `_parameter`:

```
public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly string _parameter;

    public MyJsonConverter() : this("") { }
    public MyJsonConverter(string parameter) => this._parameter = parameter;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(string);

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        _parameter + (string?)JToken.Load(reader);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer) => 
        writer.WriteValue((string)value!);
}
```

And now you will be able to deserialize as follows:

```
var _parameter = "my runtime parameter: ";
var replacementsConverters = new KeyValuePair<(Type type, string name), JsonConverter?> []
{
    new((typeof(Contract), nameof(Contract.Property)), new MyJsonConverter(_parameter)),
};
var resolver = new ConverterReplacingContractResolver(replacementsConverters)
{
    // Add any other required customizations, e.g.
    //NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
};
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = resolver,
    // Add other settings as required,
};

var contract = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contract>(json, settings);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8IsV9S).